# Conditional Grouping

Tags: sql-server

I have item and buyer tables. Both tables have their individual category tables i.e. itemCategory and buyerCategory

```
CREATE TABLE #itemCategory
(
    itemCategoryCode char(4) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    , itemCategoryName char(20) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO #itemCategory
VALUES ('I001', 'Item Category A')
    ,('I002', 'Item Category B')
    ,('I003', 'Item Category C');


CREATE TABLE #buyerCategory
(
    buyerCategoryCode char(4) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    , buyerCategoryName char(20) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO #buyerCategory
VALUES ('B001', 'Buyer Category A')
    ,('B002', 'Buyer Category B')
    ,('B003', 'Buyer Category C');

CREATE TABLE #item
(
    itemCode char(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    , itemName char(30) NOT NULL
    , itemCategoryCode char(4) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES itemCategory(itemCategoryCode)
);
INSERT INTO #item
VALUES ('IT001', 'Item A', 'I001')
    , ('IT002', 'Item AA', 'I001')
    , ('IT003', 'Item AAA', 'I001')
    , ('IT004', 'Item B', 'I002')
    , ('IT005', 'Item BB', 'I002')
    , ('IT006', 'Item BBB', 'I002')
    , ('IT007', 'Item C', 'I003')
    , ('IT008', 'Item CC', 'I003')
    , ('IT009', 'Item CCC', 'I003');

CREATE TABLE #buyer
(
    buyerCode char(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    , buyerName char(30) NOT NULL
    , buyerCategoryCode char(4) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES buyerCategory(buyerCategoryCode)
);
INSERT INTO #buyer
VALUES ('BY001', 'Buyer A', 'B001')
    , ('BY002', 'Buyer AA', 'B001')
    , ('BY003', 'Buyer AAA', 'B001')
    , ('BY004', 'Buyer B', 'B002')
    , ('BY005', 'Buyer BB', 'B002')
    , ('BY006', 'Buyer BBB', 'B002')
    , ('BY007', 'Buyer C', 'B003')
    , ('BY008', 'Buyer CC', 'B003')
    , ('BY009', 'Buyer CCC', 'B003');
```

I have a table itemRate table which define rate of item for individual buyer which also has isActive column.

```
CREATE TABLE #itemRate
(
    itemCode char(5) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES item(itemCode) 
    , buyerCode char(5) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES buyer(buyerCode)
    , [rate] int NULL
    , isActive NOT NULL BIT
);
INSERT INTO #itemRate
VALUES ('IT001', 'BY001', 3.5, '1')
    , ('IT002', 'BY001', 4.5, '1')
    , ('IT003', 'BY001', 5.5, '0')
    , ('IT004', 'BY004', 1.5, '0')
    , ('IT005', 'BY004', 2.5, '1')
    , ('IT006', 'BY004', 7.5, '0')
    , ('IT006', 'BY005', 5.5, '1')
    , ('IT005', 'BY005', 2.5, '0')
    , ('IT001', 'BY007', 2.5, '0')
    , ('IT002', 'BY008', 4.5, '0')
    , ('IT003', 'BY007', 6.5, '0');
```

I am looking for a SQL query where I can get result of following columns itemCategoryCode, buyerCategoryCode, [rate]

There can be multiple scenarios on itemRate table and in all cases query will collect MAX([rate]) column while grouping for itemCategoryCode and buyerCategoryCode

Only exception is when there is multiple items (under same itemCategory) has rates value to the same buyer (not same buyerCategory) and there are no other buyer of the same buyerCategory then system will get the MAX[rate] value of only isActive=1 records.

In the sample data of itemRate table, the result of the query should be

| itemCategoryCode | buyerCategoryCode | rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| I001 | B001 | 4.5 |
| I002 | B002 | 7.5 |
| I001 | B003 | 6.5 |

Let me explain further. a) It is not mandatory that all buyers under the same buyerCategory has any rates defined in itemRates table.

b) In the sample data, where IT003 is bought by BY001 for rate of 5.5 but because there are no other buyer (of same buyerCategory) who have bought any items of itemCategory I001, and since isActive of that record (IT003, BY001, 5.5, 0) is false, the query will not consider it in MAX.

Now compare this with sample data ('IT001', 'BY007', 2.5, '0'), ('IT002', 'BY008', 4.5, '0') and ('IT003', 'BY007', 6.5, '0'); although all this record have false value in isActive but since there are two buyers of same buyerCategory i.e. BY007 and BY008... the query will not consider isActive value hence result of MAX([rate]) would be 6.5.

I hope I clarified my requirements clearly... please let me know, if you need any further clarifications.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You said "and there are no other buyer of the same category". Does that mean "no other buyer of the same itemCategory" or "no other buyer in that buyerCategory"?

Comment: No other buyer of same buyerCategory.... if there buyer is of different buyerCategory then it will be a new record as the result would be group by buyerCategory...

Comment: In your sample data IT003 is bought by buyer BY001 for a rate of 5.5. Item IT003 is in itemCategory I001. Buyer BY001 is in buyerCategory B001, which contains 3 buyers (so your exception doesn't apply). Shouldn't the first row of your expected results have a rate of 5.5, not 4.5?

Comment: Or when you said "no other buyer of the same buyerCategory" do you mean "no other buyer of that item in the same buyerCategory"? Or perhaps "no other buyer of that itemCategory in the same buyerCategory"?

Comment: Let me explain further. a) It is not mandatory that all buyers under the same buyerCategory has any rates defined in itemRates table.

Comment: b) In the sample data, where IT003 is bought by BY001 for rate of 5.5 but because there are no other buyer (of same buyerCategory) who have bought any items of itemCategory I001, and since isActive of that record (IT003, BY001, 5.5, 0) is false, the query will not consider it in MAX.

Comment: I have add further details on the original post

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the additional detail on the requirements. I believe this gets you what you want:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #itemCategory
(
    itemCategoryCode char(4) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    , itemCategoryName char(20) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO #itemCategory
VALUES ('I001', 'Item Category A')
    ,('I002', 'Item Category B')
    ,('I003', 'Item Category C');


CREATE TABLE #buyerCategory
(
    buyerCategoryCode char(4) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    , buyerCategoryName char(20) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO #buyerCategory
VALUES ('B001', 'Buyer Category A')
    ,('B002', 'Buyer Category B')
    ,('B003', 'Buyer Category C');

CREATE TABLE #item
(
    itemCode char(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    , itemName char(30) NOT NULL
    , itemCategoryCode char(4) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES itemCategory(itemCategoryCode)
);
INSERT INTO #item
VALUES ('IT001', 'Item A', 'I001')
    , ('IT002', 'Item AA', 'I001')
    , ('IT003', 'Item AAA', 'I001')
    , ('IT004', 'Item B', 'I002')
    , ('IT005', 'Item BB', 'I002')
    , ('IT006', 'Item BBB', 'I002')
    , ('IT007', 'Item C', 'I003')
    , ('IT008', 'Item CC', 'I003')
    , ('IT009', 'Item CCC', 'I003');

CREATE TABLE #buyer
(
    buyerCode char(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    , buyerName char(30) NOT NULL
    , buyerCategoryCode char(4) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES buyerCategory(buyerCategoryCode)
);
INSERT INTO #buyer
VALUES ('BY001', 'Buyer A', 'B001')
    , ('BY002', 'Buyer AA', 'B001')
    , ('BY003', 'Buyer AAA', 'B001')
    , ('BY004', 'Buyer B', 'B002')
    , ('BY005', 'Buyer BB', 'B002')
    , ('BY006', 'Buyer BBB', 'B002')
    , ('BY007', 'Buyer C', 'B003')
    , ('BY008', 'Buyer CC', 'B003')
    , ('BY009', 'Buyer CCC', 'B003');
    
CREATE TABLE #itemRate
(
    itemCode char(5) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES item(itemCode) 
    , buyerCode char(5) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES buyer(buyerCode)
    , [rate] decimal(2,1) NULL
    , isActive bit not NULL
);
INSERT INTO #itemRate
VALUES ('IT001', 'BY001', 3.5, '1')
    , ('IT002', 'BY001', 4.5, '1')
    , ('IT003', 'BY001', 5.5, '0')
    , ('IT004', 'BY004', 1.5, '0')
    , ('IT005', 'BY004', 2.5, '1')
    , ('IT006', 'BY004', 7.5, '0')
    , ('IT006', 'BY005', 5.5, '1')
    , ('IT005', 'BY005', 2.5, '0')
    , ('IT001', 'BY007', 2.5, '0')
    , ('IT002', 'BY008', 4.5, '0')
    , ('IT003', 'BY007', 6.5, '0');

with #ratesAndCategories as
(
   select   ir.*, bu.buyerCategoryCode, it.itemCategoryCode
   from     #itemRate      ir
   join     #buyer         bu on bu.buyerCode = ir.buyerCode
   join     #item          it on it.itemCode = ir.itemCode
)

select         rc.itemCategoryCode,
               rc.buyerCategoryCode,
               --max(iif(otherBuyers.c = 0 and rc.isActive = 0, null, rc.rate))
               max(case when otherBuyers.c = 0 and rc.isActive = 0 then null else rc.rate end)
from           #ratesAndCategories     rc
cross apply    (
                  select   count(*)
                  from     #ratesAndCategories 
                  where    buyerCode != rc.buyerCode
                           and buyerCategoryCode = rc.buyerCategoryCode
                           and itemCategoryCode = rc.itemCategoryCode
               ) otherBuyers(c)      
group by       rc.itemCategoryCode,
               rc.buyerCategoryCode;
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using the older version of SQL server so IIF function is not supported. I can use CASE WHEN END instead.... correct?

Comment: @KomailNoori Yep, I have edited my answer to comment out the `iif` line and replace it with a `case` expression. But if your environment doesn't support `iif` it must be *extremely* old, ie, something prior to SQL Server 2012. If that's the case you are way way way overdue for an upgrade!